# I had Four divs contains 2 images in each div. I want to alter those Images withing each div, BUT NOT AT ONCE

Tags: javascript, image, controls, fade

Each div contains Two images. How it works explained below...

```
-div1:ImagesA.1 fade out , ImageB.1 fadeIn.
-Time Interval of 2secs.
-div2: ImageA.2 fadeOut, ImageB.2 FadeIn.
-Time Interval of 2 secs.
-div3: ImageA.3 fadeOut, ImageB.3 FadeIn.
-Time interval of 2 secs.
-div4: ImageA.4 fadeout. ImageB.4 FadeIn.

again..
-div1:ImageA.1 fadeout and ....
cycle countinous forever.
```

Comment: create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for your code or paste your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you are trying to `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` 2 images within a div at a regular time interval.

For regular time interval, you can use Javascript's `setInterval`

I have created a JSFiddle for a single `div` using [JQuery](http://jquery.com/), hope this gives you an idea.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/xFYCr/)